# Upgrading Application to Rails 4 issues with "jcrop-rails", "~> 1.0.2" gem

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

While doing bundle install facing issue

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
jcrop-rails (~> 1.0.2) ruby depends on
railties (~> 3.0) ruby

rails (= 4.0.0.rc1) ruby depends on
  railties (4.0.0.rc1)

Answer (score 1):

I would request you to check this repository. Where I have implemented jCrop with Rails4.

https://github.com/awijeet/Image_cropping_in_rails4

I would encourage you to clone it, and test it locally. Code is fair simple there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to rails 4.0.2

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
```

But no luck with jcrop-rails since is [not rails 4 ready](https://github.com/nragaz/jcrop-rails/blob/master/jcrop-rails.gemspec#L19)

However, you can get around this by using [bukalapak's fork](https://github.com/bukalapak/jcrop-rails/blob/master/jcrop-rails.gemspec#L19):

gem 'jcrop-rails', github: 'bukalapak/jcrop-rails', ref: '77bce10f6d0'

Since that gems doesn't provide tests there is no guarantee it will work until you try it out.

Comment: As I am facing lots of error while up-grading to Rails4. Decided to wait for few more days until all required gem get stabled.

Comment: Thnks for your consideration.